# How do I forecast a time series with multiple companies in R?

Tags: r, time-series, tibble, forecast

I have a dataframe that spans across 5 years, with ~500 companies and several fundamental stats (e.g. sales, # employees, ROA). Here's an example of how this could look like. Note, all numbers are just completely randomly picked, apart form the Year, obviously.

| Name | Year | Sales | Size | ROA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firm A | 2020 | 857 | 12000 | 0.45 |
| Firm B | 2020 | 112 | 3500 | 0.32 |
| Firm C | 2020 | 666 | 7000 | 0.44 |
| Firm A | 2019 | 860 | 12000 | 0.47 |
| Firm B | 2019 | 150 | 3000 | 0.31 |
| Firm C | 2019 | 700 | 6000 | 0.44 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Firm A | 2015 | 560 | 10000 | 0.47 |
| Firm B | 2015 | 100 | 2000 | 0.31 |
| Firm C | 2015 | 300 | 4000 | 0.44 |

How would you suggest I try to **forecast the 2021 ROA for each firm**, taking the span of 5 years (2015 - 2020) into consideration? I tried toying around with the `forecast` package. However, I haven't found a way to do a bulk action for all firms. My hope would be to end up with something like this:

| Name | Year | predicted ROA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Firm A | 2021 | 0.50 |
| Firm B | 2021 | 0.35 |
| Firm C | 2021 | 0.43 |

I'd be super grateful for any leads!

Comment: Use the fable package. http://fable.tidyverts.org

Comment: Hi @RobHyndman I had a look at it, but cannot seem to figure out how to do this for multiple firms. The example given would only apply to one, specific firm (or time series). Here, I have multiple time series. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use mgcv::gam for forecasting.
I used the simplest possible model where ROA only depends on the Name and a smooth function of the Year.
You'll want to increase k, depending on how much data you have (default is 10).
The `by` variable is used to split the model by Name.

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Firm A", "Firm B", "Firm C", "Firm A", 
                        "Firm B", "Firm C", "Firm A", "Firm B", "Firm C"), 
                     Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), 
                     Sales = c(857L, 112L, 666L, 860L, 150L, 700L, 560L, 100L, 300L), 
                     Size = c(12000L, 3500L, 7000L, 12000L, 3000L, 6000L, 10000L, 2000L, 4000L), 
                     ROA = c(0.45, 0.32, 0.44, 0.47, 0.31, 0.44, 0.47, 0.31, 0.44)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
gamfit <- mgcv::gam(formula = ROA ~ Name + s(Year, k = 3, by = as.factor(Name)), data = df)
summary(gamfit)
predict_df <- data.frame(Name = sort(unique(df$Name)), 
                         Year = 2021L)
predict_df$ROA <- predict(gamfit, newdata = predict_df)
```

```
predict_df
    Name Year       ROA
1 Firm A 2021 0.3969841
2 Firm B 2021 0.4098413
3 Firm C 2021 0.4055556
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Unfortunately, when trying to extend the df to 20 firms (let alone 500 firms), I receive an error that "'Calloc' could not allocate memory". Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm surprised you ran into memory problems with only 20.  My only thought would be to use a for loop to cycle through the Names.  gam has a subset argument.

Answer (score 0):

The fable package was designed for this sort of thing. Here is an artificial example that mimics the data structure in the question.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)
# Synthetic data
df <- tibble(
  Name = rep(paste("Firm",c("A","B","C")),6),
  Year = rep(2015:2020, rep(3,6)),
  ROA = runif(18)
)
# Turn it into a tsibble object
df_ts <- df %>%
  as_tsibble(index=Year, key=Name)
# Forecast each firm
fc <- df_ts %>%
  model(ARIMA(ROA)) %>%
  forecast(h=1)
fc
#> # A fable: 3 x 5 [1Y]
#> # Key:     Name, .model [3]
#>   Name   .model      Year           ROA .mean
#>   <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>        <dist> <dbl>
#> 1 Firm A ARIMA(ROA)  2021 N(0.52, 0.14) 0.517
#> 2 Firm B ARIMA(ROA)  2021 N(0.59, 0.07) 0.587
#> 3 Firm C ARIMA(ROA)  2021 N(0.52, 0.11) 0.522
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here I have used an ARIMA model, but many other models could be used instead. See my textbook at https://OTexts.com/fpp3 for many examples using fable with ARIMA and other models.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are tons of possibilities how to do this. The following solution of mine might be slightly overkill and not the ideal way to predict your problem, but is a mere representation of a scalable model workflow for time series prediction.

Check out the code below, if it gives you some interesting results and let me know. Once you got used to the tidymodels stack and the modeltime framework, this kind of data will become easy to process.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidymodels))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(modeltime))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(modeltime.ensemble))


#### DATA

h = 1

data <- data.frame(
  id = rep(paste("Firm",c("A","B","C")),6),
  date = rep(2015:2020, rep(3,6)),
  value = runif(18)
)

data <- data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = value)

data <- reshape2::melt(data, id.var='date')
dates <- ymd("2015-01-01")+ years(0:5)
dates <- rep(dates,3)
data$date <- dates
names(data)[2] = "id"

data <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  future_frame(
    .length_out = h,
    .bind_data  = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  as_tibble() 

# training- and test set
data_splits <- time_series_split(data, assess = "1 year", cumulative = TRUE)



#### PREDICT

model_fit_glmnet <- linear_reg(penalty = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") %>%
  fit(value ~ ., data = training(data_splits))

model_fit_xgboost <- boost_tree("regression",  learn_rate = 0.35) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost") %>%
  fit(value ~ ., data = training(data_splits))

ensemble <- modeltime_table(
  model_fit_glmnet,
  model_fit_xgboost
) %>%
  ensemble_weighted(loadings = c(4, 6)) 

model_tbl <- modeltime_table(ensemble)

forecast <-
  model_tbl %>%
  modeltime_forecast(
    new_data    = testing(data_splits),
    actual_data = data,
    keep_data = T
  ) %>%
  group_by(id)  


# change layout
forecast <- forecast %>% filter(str_detect(.key,  "prediction")
)
forecast <- forecast[,c(4,5,6)]
```